# No packet received, unidentified network, only on one network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ip, home-networking, dhcp

This has absolutely been doing my head in and I don't know why it happens.
There's something wrong with my wireless connection between my desktop and my router. Everytime I try to connect, I get "Identifying" for a lengthy period of time, and then "Unidentified network". No packets are received from the router, but my computer still sends them off.

I have reset my router to factory, it started working again perfectly. Just today, I hibernated my computer, and its broken again. Permanently. My computer had the network card set to "turn off to save power", I changed that to not turn it off, same issue.

I have disabled, reset, reinstalled my network drivers, still to no avail. If it helps, my network card shows as **"Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter"**.

I have reset the WiFi adapter, disabled Avast, disabled firewall, nothing happens.

I have reset winsock, the TCP/IP stack, restarted my computer, changed my DHCP settings on and off, static IP address, static IP allocation on the router, still doesn't work.

My **ipconfig** shows that yes, my DHCP is enabled, I have my Node Type set to Hybrid, but the Default Gateway is blank, and I have a "Preferred" autoconfigured IPv4 address.

Funny thing is, my Telstra router says that the computer is connected, but still isn't having any communication. Also, this only happens on my home network. Use my hotspot? Works fine. Use my Raspberry Pi as a router and have it **bridge to the same router I can't connect to**, works fine.

This is not the normal type of question I would ask, but I have absolutely no idea what to do. Anyone know what to do from here?

[image: ipconfig all]

[image: packet loss]

[image: auto dhcp]

Comment: Which Windows version is this? You should be able to browse the available WiFi networks and select the specific network you want to connect to. At present your IP address `169.254...` is self-selected, because DHCP requests met with no response. Possible reasons are wrong password (I've had problems with WEP in Win10) and MAC address exclusion.

Comment: @AFH Thanks for helping! I'm running Windows 10 Pro, and yes, while I can select it, it just "Identifying" loops and finally can't identify it. Checked my Security tab for the wifi, the network key is correct, I even forgot the network and reconnected, same issue. MAC address isn't been excluded, I just reset the modem 2 days ago. Network is WPA2

Comment: The only other time I've seen this sort of problem is with a weak WiFi signal or when there is a clash between the original router and a network extender. In the first case you could try to forget the network you have been trying to connect to, then set up the WiFi manually: Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Centre -> Set up a new connection or network -> Manually connect to a wireless network. In the second case disconnect the repeater or rename its SSID.

Comment: @AFH In actual fact, the signal is *slightly* weaker than I would like. Its 4 rooms away, and I get 2-3 bars instead of the usual 4. Will try what you said now.

Comment: In that case try setting up the connection by moving closer to the router. If the connection is then correctly established, it may well continue to work once you move it back to its more remote location. If not, consider improving your WiFi signal: (1) try manually configuring the router's channnel; (2) if available, try an external aerial; or (3) use a range extender, preferably based on power-line networking, rather than rebroadcasting the received WiFi.

Comment: @AFH Since its a desktop firmly in place, and the router is basically non-portable also, I can't move it closer. Trying to setup a seperate modem to bridge to it now as an extender. Thankyou AFH.

Comment: @AFH Yep, as I thought, stuck a repeater in and it works perfectly. I'm not posting this as an answer however because it still doesn't solve the original problem, just a physical workaround. Thankyou for the suggestions!

Comment: A work-round is not necessarily a bad answer, so don't be inhibited from answering on that assumption. I shan't submit an answer myself, as I was just suggesting a number of possible approaches. Others may appreciate seeing that there is a solution of sorts.